# How to add columns names as first row to DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like one given below. I want to add it's columns names as first row to the same DataFrame. I tried to concatenate it with itself but it didn't work/ how can I do it to get result as in desired output?

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({"Sales QTY":[10,20,30,40],
                 "Sales Person":['Jack', 'Adam', 'Ken', 'Jack'],
                 "Product":["Apple", "Orange","Apple","Cherry"]
                 })
df=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df.columns),df])
df

desired output
df=pd.DataFrame({"Sales QTY":['Sales QTY', 10,20,30,40],
                 "Sales Person":["Sales Person", 'Jack', 'Adam', 'Ken', 'Jack'],
                 "Product":["Product", "Apple", "Orange","Apple","Cherry"]
                 })
```

Comment: Use the pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data) function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution could be:

```
df.loc[-1] = df.columns
print(df.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Sales QTY  Sales Person  Product
0  Sales QTY  Sales Person  Product
1         10          Jack    Apple
2         20          Adam   Orange
3         30           Ken    Apple
4         40          Jack   Cherry
```

Comment: this negative one is amazing

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html#pandas.DataFrame.agg) to create a DataFrame with its column names as a row and then [`concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) this with the original DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Sales QTY": [10, 20, 30, 40],
                   "Sales Person": ['Jack', 'Adam', 'Ken', 'Jack'],
                   "Product": ["Apple", "Orange", "Apple", "Cherry"]
                   })

df = pd.concat([df.agg([lambda ser: ser.name]), df], ignore_index=True)
```

The advantage of this is that it can be used in method chaining if you like, e.g.:

```
import pandas as pd

df = (pd.DataFrame({"Sales QTY": [10, 20, 30, 40],
                   "Sales Person": ['Jack', 'Adam', 'Ken', 'Jack'],
                   "Product": ["Apple", "Orange", "Apple", "Cherry"]
                   })
      .pipe(lambda df_: pd.concat([df_.agg([lambda ser: ser.name]), df_], ignore_index=True))
      )
```